# PHP & HTML: how to set url to home page

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I go to the home page of my website, it does not have a default id in url. 
How can I set a default id to my home page's url.

I want this : www.afgclick.com&id = 2

Comment: Do you need the `id` to be in the URL or can you just say `if (!$_GET['id']) $_GET['id'] = 1;`?

Comment: @Hamid Ebadi, where are you accessing your homepage from? if it is from a link, then just simply add that value to the link.

Comment: I removed MySQL tag, as it's completely unrelated. Please use only related tags

Comment: @JuanCastellon no I'm not accessing it from link.

Comment: This kind of URL structure is used in order to pass data to the user agent in order to conduct an HTTP transaction using the URI. To put it short, you do this for a reason. `So, what is your reason?`

Comment: When for the first time I enter to the home page, I want url includes that id automatically. @Albzi

Comment: @Rüzgar
My website would be multiple language so when users enter to the home page for the first time I want that url alrady includes 'lang' by default.

Comment: Thanks guy! I found the answer 
if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
    
}

Answer (score 3):

Just add a check to see if and `id` is set, and if not, redirect to the same url WITH that `id`.

In PHP: (thanks @Albzi)

```
if (!$_GET['id']) $_GET['id'] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need that parameter in the URL but you dont own the link that gets you to that page then try using something like:

**HTML version**

1. Create an index.html file containing the following code in the head section:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=www.afgclick.com&id=2" />`

**Javascript version**

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){location.href="http://www.afgclick.com&id=2"} , 3000);
```

**PHP version**

```
function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303){
   header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
   die();
}
```

Good luck!